# How do I get the class object of Class with type parameters in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-erasure

I'm new to Scala and rusty with Java and I'm tripping up on some semantics. I'm trying to get the class object of [SequenceFileOutputFormat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/src-html/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/SequenceFileOutputFormat.html#line.42).

Other stack overflow posts say to simple do the following:

```
classOf[SequenceFileOutputFormat]
```

Which yields the error:

```
class SequenceFileOutputFormat takes type parameters
```

Ok fine, so it requires the parameter types, so I do the following:

```
classOf[SequenceFileOutputFormat[String, String]]
```

Which yields the error:

```
[error]  found   : Class[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat[String,String]](classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat])
[error]  required: Class[_ <: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputFormat[_, _]]
```

What gives? How do I get the class object of a class that requires type parameters?

Comment: Does `classOf[SequenceFileOutputFormat[_, _]]` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `hadoop-mapreduce-client-core` "3.0.0", this here:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output._

object HadoopQuestion_48818781 {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val c = classOf[SequenceFileOutputFormat[_, _]]
    println("Class: " + c)
  }
}
```

prints:

```
Class: class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.SequenceFileOutputFormat
```

**Explanation:**

Even though `classOf[T]` is processed at compile time, the `Class[T]` thing itself is a runtime construct, and it does not know anything about the generic type parameters of `T`. Therefore, you have to put underscores `_` for the runtime-erased type parameters. These underscores are really just syntactic sugar for *existential types* in Scala, but in this particular case they fulfill a role similar to that of the wildcards in Java.